# ReactJS: element.ScrollLeft does not change value after resizing window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, scroll, state

I have a state called `scrollStatus`, where I track the current scroll position of a div, and I set its value using a ref and `element.scrollLeft` when scrolling:

```
const scrollHandle = () => {
setScrollStatus(container.current?.scrollLeft);
console.log(scrollStatus);
}
```

So when doing `console.log` I get a different value of `scrollStatus`, which is what I want:

[image]

When I resize the window by a large margin (let's say from desktop to mobile view), the scroll value will change drastically, which I expected for it to happen since my container's width is percentage based.

Here in the console, you can see the value changed to `375` after I resize the window to mobile view:

[image]

However, when I try to scroll again after resizing the window, the value of `scrollStatus` doesn't change. It retains the current position value after I resize the window:

[image]

(The value still won't change even if I resize the window again)

Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: mobile view is smaller than window view, right?

Comment: Yes, I resized from desktop to mobile view and vice versa.

Comment: Can you show where/how you're adding your `scrollHandle` event handler? If possible, it would make it easier for us to debug your program if you could create [mre] which is a piece of code that reproduces your issue. You can use [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) to help, or if using the stack snippet doesn't work you can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to create the reproducible example.

Comment: @NickParsons sorry for the delay. I tried to reproduce the example on sandbox but I don't seem to encounter the problem there. As I change the responsive view, the value changes. Anyways, here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-burnell-igdnm?file=/src/App.tsx&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Comment: I arrived here because I found same issue within angular appliction